# linux ls -l ACL +, . , gap How to make gap

Tags: linux, ls, acl, setfacl

```
drwxr-xr-x+   4 root root 4096 Sep 21 04:00 test     << +
drwxrwxrwt.  10 root root  250 Sep 21 04:03 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  12 root root  144 Sep 19 03:42 usr      << .
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root  278 Sep 19 03:52 var
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  278 Sep 19 03:52 test1     <<<why
```

if there is a ACL setting value = " + "

if there is no ACL setting value = " . "

But last directory test1 have gap.
why is there a blank space here
and

How can I create that blank space?

Comment: IIRC `.` is for SELinux contexts. Remove the context and ACL and you will get no character there. But why do you want that?

Comment: I want to know the exact reason why the gap occurs.

Comment: The gap is the default. It's only when you have something additional like SELInux contexts or ACLs that something is put there.

Comment: Are the columns really misaligned or is it a problem in your copy paste?

Comment: You can run `getfattr -dm- -- *` to see ACLs / security content and other extended attributes on those files which would explain the presence of those `.` and `+` flags.

Comment: IOW, is your question about that broken column alignment (which I can't reproduce, what's your implementation and version of `ls`?) or why there is no `.` nor `+` after the permissions?

Comment: It was helpful. ACL / security content problem is correct

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood the characters that `ls` shows in that position.  This is from the info page for the GNU `ls` command (i.e., `info coreutils ls`), at the end of the section that describes the letters used in the permissions/mode field ([available online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#index-long-ls-format)):

> Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies whether an alternate access method such as an access control list applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is a printing character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU ‘`ls`’ uses a ‘`.`’ character to indicate a file with a security context *[[other than `unlabeled`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?h=v9.4#n3537)]*, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is marked with a ‘`+`’ character.

Comment: And if there's neither ACL nor security context, there is no character added after the permission, but if there are other files in the listing that have a `.` or `+`, `ls` puts a space there (not shown in the OP's sample) but that's only for alignment.

Comment: Or `info coreutils 'long ls format'` or `info ls long` to get to that section.